# Опрос о сохранение при закрытии формы

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как сделать опрос пользователя при закрытии формы, только если он что-то менял на ней?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В класс формы или куда-нибудь в доступное место:

```
public bool UpdateInForm = false;
```

В обработчики:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateInForm = true;
}
```

И на обработчик закрытия формы:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (UpdateInForm)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Сохранить изменения?", "Внимание", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // Сохраняем
        }
        else if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        {
            //Не сохраняем
        }
        else e.Cancel = true;//Отменяем действие
    }
}
```

Comment: И как оно проверяет что производились изменения?

Comment: Мы на текстбоксы и другие контролы вешаем события изменения:

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateInForm = true;
}

или

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateInForm = true;
}

Comment: Это конечно всё замечательно но что если у меня на форме очень много контролов - http://s017.radikal.ru/i429/1308/27/23df36367ab0.png
Я устану на каждый вещать событие. Есть более радикальный метод?

Comment: Как-то так..


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Control a in this.Controls)
            {
                a.TextChanged += a_TextChanged;
                ((CheckBox)a).CheckedChanged += Form1_CheckedChanged;
            }
        
        }

        void Form1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateInForm = true;
        }

        void a_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateInForm = true;
        }

- Деревянное решение, нужно доработать.

Answer (score 1):

используйте [Form.DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx)

```
Form form = new Form();
if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    //действия
}
else
{
    //действия
}
```

Comment: Да не так. Как мне узнать изменялось ли что-нибудь на форме или нет. И только если что-то вводили или изменяли только тогда опрашивать